# Intermediate Value Theorem and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus question

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity, convex-analysis

I received a question on a previous exam, but I had no clue how to go about doing it.  I know I'm supposed to use the MVT, IVT and FTC, but I'm not sure where.  The question is

Suppose $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, with $f(x)\geq0$ on $[a,b]$, and that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.  Assuming that $f(x)g(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, show that $\exists c\in[a,b]$ so that $$\int^b_af(x)g(x)dx=g(c)\int^b_af(x)dx.$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g(x)$ takes its maximum and minimum values $M$ and $m$ on $[a,b]$.
Say, $g(x_1)=M$ and $g_(x_2)=m$. Then
$$g(x_1)\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=M\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
\ge\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx\ge m\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=g(x_2)\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$
Can you now see why there is a $c\in[a,b]$ with
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx=g(c)\int_a^b f(x)\,dx?$$

Comment: I can basically use that fact that $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous, and apply the IVT to find the $c$ that I'm looking for. Am I correct?

Comment: @Ben Apply IVT to $x\mapsto g(x)\int_a^bf(t)dt$